# C++ object declaration and no default constructor (user-declared or implicitly-declared)

Tags: c++, constructor, default

If I have

```
class Something
{
public:
    Something(int whatever) : whatever_(whatever) {}
private:
    int whatever_;
}
```

Then what happens when I create an object on the stack

```
Something something;
```

since there is no default constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a conforming compiler you get a compilation error.

The following code:

```
class Something
{
public:
    Something(int whatever) : whatever_(whatever) {}
private:
    int whatever_;
};

Something something;
```

When compiled with gcc8.2 results in the following compilation error:

```
<source>:9:11: error: no matching function for call to 'Something::Something()' 
 Something something;
           ^~~~~~~~~    
<source>:4:5: note: candidate: 'Something::Something(int)'    
     Something(int whatever) : whatever_(whatever) {}    
     ^~~~~~~~~    
<source>:4:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided    
<source>:1:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Something::Something(const Something&)'    
 class Something    
       ^~~~~~~~~    
<source>:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided    
<source>:1:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Something::Something(Something&&)'    
<source>:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided    
Compiler returned: 1
```

Live example available at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/l3xazV).

Comment: Can you add a ; after the last } and try again? It compiles for me.

Comment: Yes, a typo, fixed.

Comment: @MartinF So what compiler, compiler version and compiler options are you using?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't do a clean build after removing the default constructor. It's complaining now. Sorry...